# how to place arabic in NSURLConnection

Tags: iphone, ios, url, nsurlconnection, arabic

I have to put arabic in NSURLConnection, but the problem is that when I am not able to see arabic string properly using NSLog I get following string.

```
   Country is ÿßŸÑÿ•ŸÖÿßÿ±ÿßÿ™ ÿßŸÑÿπÿ±ÿ®Ÿäÿ© ÿßŸÑŸÖÿ™ÿ≠ÿØÿ©
```

and if I pass from NSURLConnection I get

```
 http://xxxxxx.com/api/api.php?func=showAllCompaniesCategoriesCountryWise&params[]=ÿßŸÑÿ•ŸÖÿßÿ±ÿßÿ™ ÿßŸÑÿπÿ±ÿ®Ÿäÿ© ÿßŸÑŸÖÿ™ÿ≠ÿØÿ©&params[]=all
```

bad URL

```
         Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000 "bad URL" UserInfo=0x2f0b00 {NSUnderlyingError=0x2f1130 "bad URL", NSLocalizedDescription=bad URL}
```

So, please help me, how can I solve this problem.

Comment: Have you tried encoding for your string 
[string stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
[string stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]

Comment: You should also use an `NSMutableURLRequest` and set the `HTTPMethod` to `POST`. Then, change your php page from `$_GET['param']` to `$_POST['param']`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `- (NSString *)stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding` to create a proper string for `NSURL`.

Comment: See RFC2396 Section 2.1 for a little deeper explanation about why this is required, even though the spec implies it shouldn't be. http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt